DeleteFiles Task not working as expected in Azure DevOps Build Pipeline
I am trying to delete files after build task, I need to delete Images folder and some of the dll files from Bin directory, I have configure the delete files task as below. but somehow files are not being delete and all files are published to Artifact.
Images
bin/Devex*.dll
**/Images
*/bin/Devex.dll
Build Task
DeleteFiles Task Log
Artifact should not contain Images folder and some of the dll files(Devex*.dll)

Then issue should be caused by that the directory is not correctly specified between your build, delete files, and publish artifact tasks. You need to check the output folder, then the files can be deleted in correct location. I added the details in the reply below, thanks.

Then issue should be caused by that the directory is not correctly specified.
In Delete files task, you have specified $(Agent.BuildDirectory), it's predefined variable which points to D:\a\1. Please check the output of Build Solution task, confirm the directory, then use correct folder for Delete files task so the task can find the files to delete.
For Publish build artifacts task, the Path to publish is $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory), it points to D:\a\1\a on windows agent, please make sure you used correct file path(the folder after deleting dll, images) to publish.
To fix the error, for example:

For Build Solution task, you can set the output directory with msbuild argument /p:OutDir=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory).



Use $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) for the delete files task, so it can find the files to delete. Please also fix the content as well.



In Publish build artifacts task, you can use the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) path to publish then.

